# "idle-vue": "^2.0.5", does not detect page scroll event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am tracking inactivity by user in vue application using following URL.

https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-set-timer-idle-in-vue-1f4b57beb886

This works well, However it does not track application page scroll event, if I am keep scrolling application page it does not listen and still pops message of inactivity.

Anyone had faced similar issue.

Also it does also applies inactivity tracker at login page that I dont want.

//UPDATE: I got one answer for event:

I got answers on how to track scroll event as below :

```
const eventsHub = new Vue();
Vue.use(IdleVue, {
  eventEmitter: eventsHub,
  store,
  idleTime: 3000, // 3 seconds
  startAtIdle: false,
  events:['mousemove', 'keydown', 'mousedown', 'touchstart',"scroll"]
});
```

One can add event property and define all events which breaks idleness of the page/application. (Hopefully this would help someone )

But I am looking answer on how to untrack inactivity once user redirects to login page.

Answer (score 0):

All right folks, I manage to get answer, as I already answered on how to track scroll event in my original question, below is the answer if I want to untrack activity for login page or any specific example. In App.vue you need to mention below stuff: (for me it was login page which I was looking for untrack)

```
     computed: {
        isIdle() {
            return this.$store.state.idleVue.isIdle && this.$route.path.split('/')[2] != 'login';
        }
```

Hope this would help someone in same situation.